# Multiple proxy:errors in /var/log/apache2/error.log

Tags: server, apache2, proxy

I am not sure where these warnings are for/concerning. Should I be worried about them or just ignore them as people are trying to connect to my server? Proxy Mod is already enabled, however I am less concerned about this and more the fact my apache instance is showing random ip's and web addresses that are trying to be proxied :?

```
[Mon Dec 13 19:49:12.127111 2021] [proxy:warn] [pid 992000] [client 162.55.232.112:45408] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL 192.169.152.51:443 (scheme '192.169.152.51'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Mon Dec 13 19:49:12.203528 2021] [proxy:warn] [pid 992002] [client 162.55.235.124:49258] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL 192.169.152.51:443 (scheme '192.169.152.51'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Mon Dec 13 19:49:12.825123 2021] [proxy:warn] [pid 992004] [client 162.55.232.112:48362] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL www.mining-cast.com:443 (scheme 'www.mining-cast.com'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Mon Dec 13 19:49:13.158784 2021] [proxy:warn] [pid 992010] [client 162.55.232.116:39704] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL sdk.finance:443 (scheme 'sdk.finance'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Mon Dec 13 19:49:14.867535 2021] [proxy:warn] [pid 992009] [client 176.9.19.26:45758] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL www.mining-cast.com:443 (scheme 'www.mining-cast.com'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Mon Dec 13 19:49:14.988339 2021] [proxy:warn] [pid 992003] [client 162.55.235.124:33712] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL portugiptv.com:443 (scheme 'portugiptv.com'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Mon Dec 13 19:49:15.730902 2021] [proxy:warn] [pid 992001] [client 162.55.232.116:54246] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL sdk.finance:443 (scheme 'sdk.finance'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Mon Dec 13 19:49:17.591263 2021] [proxy:warn] [pid 992000] [client 162.55.232.112:41990] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL beastiptv.best:443 (scheme 'beastiptv.best'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Mon Dec 13 19:49:19.224691 2021] [proxy:warn] [pid 992002] [client 176.9.19.26:41162] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL dossiers-du-rocher.com:443 (scheme 'dossiers-du-rocher.com'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Mon Dec 13 19:49:20.844906 2021] [ssl:error] [pid 992010] [remote 192.185.52.242:443] AH01961: SSL Proxy requested for localhost.localdomain:80 but not enabled [Hint: SSLProxyEngine]
[Mon Dec 13 19:49:20.844960 2021] [proxy:error] [pid 992010] AH00961: HTTPS: failed to enable ssl support for 192.185.52.242:443 (www.standuptoracism.org.uk)
```

### apache2 mods

```
root@localhost:~# apache2ctl -M
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931987/apache-proxy-no-protocol-handler-was-valid) help?

Comment: I had actually tried everything on that suggested question. I think though, what is worrying is. I see these warnings directly after a apache restart. But I have zero idea as to what these refer to. They are not my domains/ip's. :/

Comment: Silly question, but have you checked your virtual host configuration files to confirm there are no references to the domains or IPs listed? Are you using `mod_proxy` to pass traffic from this web server to a different destination? 

Comment: I think its just good you're asking :D `mod_proxy` is exactly for that. Passing npm through apache. I can confirm that all the `*.conf` files are my own without those ips/domains in them. Weird indeed this is

Comment: Would you mind listing the contents of `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` ?

Comment: Added @nate T let me know if that's enough

Comment: Have you tried enabling *mod_proxy_http2*? According to the [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html), *mod_proxy_http* is for http1.1. I've never used that module before, so its just a guess, but the a2 debian docs are pretty trustworthy.

Comment: The wierd ips are likely generated by a require directive in a .conf file. Do you have any packages on your machine that use cgi-bin, like `dwww` or similar? Try using `cat` in a for loop over all *.conf files in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled`, and grep the result against an ip-like pattern. I bet there will be a few strange ips in the result. (I think `\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}` will work, but didnt try it, so you may need to change it up.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have enabled proxy module. You need to disable it with

```
a2dismod proxy
```

May be there are some other mod's you need to disable.
To see what else modules you can (should) disable check output of

```
apache2ctl -M
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Sorry but these are already enabled:` proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)` I realised in my hast to create the question I did not highlight the fact I do "care" that proxy mod is enabled/disabled. I'd like to understand _why_ it is asking for proxies to these random places

Answer (score 0):

Ok here how to enable mod_proxy.

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
a2enmod proxy_balancer
a2enmod lbmethod_byrequests
systemctl restart apache2
```

Apart from your proxy you need to have one (or more) http-servers that deliver the content.

http://10.10.0.100  - Proxy Server

http://192.168.0.11 - Content Server

Edit /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf and change virtualhost section to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.11/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.11/
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart Apache

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

Now if you access your proxy server (http://10.10.0.100) in a web browser, you will see the response of your backend server (http://192.168.0.11)